# How do I get this look on my app?

Tags: java, user-interface, android

https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1aJr.jpg

I have seen a few apps use this look and I think it looks great so I would like my app to look like this too.

I've tried making a ListView and used "simple_list_item_1" for it but that is just a plain black background with white text.

Also, can my app look like that and still be available for android 2.1 and up?

Comment: Extremely vague. What about "this look" are you trying to emulate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is the Holo.Light theme basically, available in Android 4.0+

There is a project called HoloEverywhere:
https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere

That is porting (screenshots showing the dark theme), the Holo theme look to android 1.6+

Answer (score 1):

They may have used a few custom color options though it essentially looks like stock themes.

Check out the following Android dev resources.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

http://developer.android.com/design/style/themes.html